memory allocation exceeds memory.max value set for cgroupsv2
I'm working on an app that generates artificial memory load, and I'm using cgroups to monitor the app at runtime and check what happens in proximity of the limit.
In its simplest version, the app allocates a 20Mi buffer once every second and then stores it in a key/value structure where the value is the buffer and the key is a checksum on the buffer. At each iteration all the structure is checked to see if the buffers changed compared to their value when the hash was computed.
The source is in golang and it looks like the following:
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha256"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    const bufSize = 20*1024*1024
    mem := make(map[[32]byte][]byte)

    for {
        buf := make([]byte, bufSize)

        // Checking buffer
        if buf == nil {
            log.Fatal("make() returned nil buffer")
            return
        } else if len(buf) != bufSize {
            log.Fatal("make() returned buffer size different than requested")
            return
        }

        // Filling buffer
        for i := range buf {
            buf[i] = byte(rand.Intn(256))
        }

        // computing checksum on buffer and store in map
        sha := sha256.Sum256(buf)
        mem[sha] = buf

        // check hashes of previously allocated buffers
        for hash, buf := range mem {
            curHash := sha256.Sum256(buf)
            if hash != curHash {
                log.Fatalf("Memory corruption!")
            } else {
                fmt.Printf("  OK: %x\n      %x\n\n", hash[:5], curHash[:5])
            }
        }
        log.Printf("Memory check ok!")

        time.Sleep(1*time.Second)
    }
}

Then the cgroup has been set up with the following scenario:
controlled shell (that will execute the app)
bash -- so that the terminal stays alive
echo $$ -- get PID of the bash
controlling shell
mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/cage/
echo 100000000 > /sys/fs/cgroup/cage/memory.max -- setting 100M limit
echo $SHELL_PID > /sys/fs/cgroup/cage/cgroup.procs -- where SHELL_PID is the controlled shell's PID
controlled shell
echo /proc/$$/cgroup -- check that the process has been confined
observing shells
one shell with watch -n .3 -t "cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cage/memory.current | awk '{print \$1/(1024*1024)}'" -- cgroup memory consumption
one shell with watch -n .3 -t free -m -- for overall system memory consumption
controlled shell
go run .
At this point the memory consumption of the cgroup shows a stable value (95 in my case), while the application keeps allocating and checks passing, and the overall memory consumption gets higher by a visible 20M each second.
The kernel documentation page of the cgroups says for memory.max:

Memory usage hard limit.  This is the final protection
mechanism.  If a cgroup's memory usage reaches this limit and
can't be reduced, the OOM killer is invoked in the cgroup.
Under certain circumstances, the usage may go over the limit
temporarily.

I was also asking myself what are those circumstances.

Found Documentation: Clarify usage of memory limits which is a patch on the Linux documentation mailing list which changes the wording of the quoted paragraph from the Kernel documentation page. Does the contents of the referenced patch answer your question?

It is a hint that the documentation may be slightly out of date. But the content of the patch suggests that memory.max is the last limit, that triggers the oom, which in my case it doesn't happen.

I was misguided by the output of free(1), that actually shows the memory consumption in the Memory row at the used column after each new allocation, despite memory.current value being the same for the cgroup.
Then when memory.max is reached, nothing happens to the process. That keeps allocating correctly.
If monitored, memory.swap.current shows an increase in its value when very close to the value of memory.max (but never touching it). So in proximity of memory.max, allocations saved in the map are moved to the swap 20M (roughly) at a time, leaving space for a new 20M allocation, and swapped back into memory when accessed for the hash check.
Setting a limit to memory.swap.max has the intended effect of invoking the OOM-killer on the process, that is, when both limits are met.
